# Get text in the URL with dynamic date - Regex Java

Tags: java, regex, string

I need to get the text between the URL which has a date in Java

**Input 1:**

```
/test1/raw/2019-06-11/testcustomer/usr/pqr/DATA/mn/export/
```

**Output:** `testcustomer`

Only `/raw/` remains, `date` will change and `testcustomer` will change

**Input 2:**

```
/test3/raw/2018-09-01/newcustomer/usr/pqr/DATA/mn/export/
```

**Output:** `newcustomer`

```
String url = "/test3/raw/2018-09-01/newcustomer/usr/pqr/DATA/mn/export/";
String customer = getCustomer(url);
public String getCustomer (String _url){
    String source = "default";
    String regex = basePath + "/raw/\\d{4}-\\d{2}-\\d{2}/usr*";
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile(regex);
    Matcher m = p.matcher(_url);
    if (m.find()) {
        source = m.group(1);
    } else {
        logger.error("Cant get customer with regex " + regex);
    }
    return source;
}
```

It's returning `'default'` :(

Comment: Have you tried anything ?

Comment: Yes, let me add it

Comment: @V next time think about adding the code at first time you write, it can go reaaaally quick to get downvote because of no vote ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your regex `/raw/\\d{4}-\\d{2}-\\d{2}/usr*` is missing the part for the value you want, you need a regex that find the date, and keep what's next :

1. `/\w*/raw/[0-9-]+/(\w+)/.*` or `(?<=raw\/\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}\/)(\w+)` will be good

   ```
   Pattern p = Pattern.compile("/\\w*/raw/[0-9-]+/(\\w+)/.*");
   Matcher m = p.matcher(str);
   if (m.find()) {
       String value = m.group(1);
       System.out.println(value);
   }
   ```
2. Or if it's always the 4th part, use `split()`

   ```
   String value = str.split("/")[4];
   System.out.println(value);
   ```

And here a [`>> code demo`](https://ideone.com/Ag19qw)

Answer (score 2):

Here, we can likely use `raw` followed by the date as a left boundary, then we would collect our desired output in a capturing group, we would add an slash and consume the rest of our string, with an expression similar to:

```
.+raw\/[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}\/(.+?)\/.+
```

#### [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/A3KMgU/1/)

#### Test

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

final String regex = ".+raw\\/[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}\\/(.+?)\\/.+";
final String string = "/test1/raw/2019-06-11/testcustomer/usr/pqr/DATA/mn/export/\n"
     + "/test3/raw/2018-09-01/newcustomer/usr/pqr/DATA/mn/export/";

final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex, Pattern.MULTILINE);
final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string);

while (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println("Full match: " + matcher.group(0));
    for (int i = 1; i <= matcher.groupCount(); i++) {
        System.out.println("Group " + i + ": " + matcher.group(i));
    }
}
```

#### RegEx

If this expression wasn't desired or you wish to modify it, please visit [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/A3KMgU/1/).

#### RegEx Circuit

[jex.im](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24) visualizes regular expressions:

[image]